# How to get GROUP_CONCAT only for rows with maximum value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Suppose, we have a table:

```
SELECT * FROM users_to_courses;
+---------+-----------+------------+---------+
| user_id | course_id | pass_date  | file_id |
+---------+-----------+------------+---------+
|       1 |         1 | 2014-01-01 |       1 |
|       1 |         1 | 2014-01-01 |       2 |
|       1 |         1 | 2014-02-01 |       3 |
|       1 |         1 | 2014-02-01 |       4 |
+---------+-----------+------------+---------+
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `users_to_courses` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `course_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pass_date` date NOT NULL,
  `file_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `course_id`, `pass_date`, `file_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

One user can pass a certain course multiple times, and every time he passes multiple certificates can be generated. `user_id` and `course_id` store the links to users and courses tables. file_id - to files table, where info about certificate files is stored.

In our example user #1 has passed course #1 twice and every time 2 certificates were issued: 4 records totally.

How can I get this data: for user_id=1 for every course get MAX(pass_date) and all the files, attached to this date. So far I could only get this:

```
SELECT
    users_to_courses.course_id,
    MAX(users_to_courses.pass_date) AS max_passed_date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(users_to_courses.file_id SEPARATOR ',') AS files   
FROM
    users_to_courses
WHERE
    users_to_courses.user_id=1
GROUP BY
    users_to_courses.course_id;

+-----------+-----------------+---------+
| course_id | max_passed_date | files   |
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
|         1 | 2014-02-01      | 1,2,3,4 |
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
```

I need this:

```
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
| course_id | max_passed_date | files   |
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
|         1 | 2014-02-01      |   3,4   |
+-----------+-----------------+---------+
```

I think, this requires a compound GROUP BY.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66948/2)

Comment: Your data appears to be saying that he passed the course **4** times, twice on two different days.  Is that a valid case?  If so, you probably need at least an additional table to be able to correctly support your data...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse no, he passed twice and received 2 certificates for each pass. Do you think, this data can be normalized?

Comment: The problem is that based on this table alone the interpretation of it is ambiguous - either way of viewing it is correct, you need meta information (like knowledge that people can't take the same test twice on the same day).  If you can only take a test once per day, you're okay.  If you can take it more than once you need some sort of `attemptId` column, which probably does mean a new cross-reference file between that and `file_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below query it first gets max date for all the records and then we can join only those record in the outer query. You can use the same query for more than one user by adding `group by utc.user_id`

```
SELECT
    utc.course_id,
    mdt.maxDate AS max_passed_date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(utc.file_id SEPARATOR ',') AS files
FROM
    users_to_courses utc
    join
(SELECT MAX(pass_date) AS maxDate, course_id cId, user_id uId
        FROM users_to_courses GROUP BY user_id, course_id) AS mdt
ON
    mdt.uId = utc.user_id
AND
    mdt.cId = utc.course_id
AND 
    mdt.maxDate = utc.pass_date
WHERE
    utc.user_id=1
GROUP BY
    utc.course_id;
```

Comment: I wonder if it's more efficient to put the WHERE into the subquery? And the exclusion of maxdate from the GROUP BY is a little icky.

Comment: @Strawberry If you can suggest a more efficient solution, please post is as a different answer.